# Extract unique terms from a PANDAS series

Tags: python, performance, regex, numpy, pandas

## Background

I have process tons of DataFrames with shapes of ~230 columns x ~2000-50000+ rows. Here is an extremely simplified example;

```
 numbers                colors
0    0.03620894806802     1xYellow ; 2xRed 
1  0.7641262315308163  2xYellow ; 1xOrange 
2  0.5607449770945651   3xYellow ; 2xGreen 
3  0.6714547913365702     1xYellow ; 1xRed 
4  0.8646309438322237     2xYellow ; 1xRed
```

## Problem

I need to break the `colors` column down to a set that looks like this;
`{'Green', 'Orange', 'Red', 'Yellow'}`. The example code below can do this but it is painfully slow on huge DataFrames.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Generating example data
color = ["1xYellow ; 2xRed ",
         "2xYellow ; 1xOrange ",
         "3xYellow ; 2xGreen ",
         "1xYellow ; 1xRed ",
         "2xYellow ; 1xRed "]
numbers = np.random.rand(len(color))
ex_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([numbers,color]).T,
                     columns = ["numbers","colors"])
# Compile the regex to apply with findall
rx = re.compile("x(\w+)\s")
just_colors = ex_df.colors.apply(rx.findall)
# Below is the painfully slow operation that needs optimization.  
present_colors = set(sum(just_colors,[]))
```

## Question

Is there a better method out there for pulling unique terms out of a pandas series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like you really need regular expressions.  This construct just using basic string operations is about 10x faster than the construct with the regular expressions:

```
present_colors = set()
for value in ex_df['colors'].values:
    for color in [x.strip() for x in value.split(';')]:
        present_colors.add(color.split('x')[-1])
```

And a bit faster yet, go with the same code as a generator using itertools:

```
import itertools as it
present_colors = set(it.chain.from_iterable(
    ([color.split('x')[-1].strip() for color in value.split(';')]
     for value in ex_df['colors'].values)))
```

Comment: So using `%timeit` in jupyter notebook doing it the old way I get; 1 loop, best of 3: 20.3 s per loop, and the itertools way I get; 10 loops, best of 3: 37.2 ms per loop! Hell yeah. Thanks again!

Comment: *On a df with shape of (44919, 123) with Intel Core i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Stephen Rauch's answer, here's a bit of background regarding regular expressions and why they aren't suitable in this case. (Note that my answer is about regexes in general, not about how python handles them.)

Behind the scenes regular expressions tend to work by building a state machine that operates on the individual characters of a string, and does a fair bit of work regarding captures and matching multiple characters. Thus regular expressions are optimal for patterns that have a degree of complexity, and in cases such as yours where the pattern is a simple matter of 'sections separated by single characters' they generally perform much worse than a simple character split.

For example, let's pull apart the regex you use in your code: `"x(\w+)\s"`. (Note that my emphasis is not on what the regex means, but what must be done behind the scenes to implement the regex.)

- `x` is simple enough, that's just a simple per-character match which
  is just a matter of iterating through the source to find a matching
  `x`.
- `(` begins a match, which may be as simple as pushing the character
  index on the stack, or may involve object creation depending on the
  approach used.
- `\w` is a bit more complicated. This time instead of comparing each
  character to another character, each character is being compared to a
  set of characters. It's still (mostly) a constant time operation if
  the implementation is using a [hash
  set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), but it's more
  complicated than pushing an index or comparing two characters.
- `+` is again more complicated. It's effectively a 'while' loop, which
  repeats the previous operation until it no longer matches. Firstly,
  this is implicitly a branching operation, which adds a bit of
  complexity in itself. Secondly, the previous operation was not
  completely trivial and that operation is now being repeated several
  times, which mounts up.
- `)` removes the earlier index from the stack and adds a capture to
  the capture list that starts at the removed index and continues to
  the index of the last matched character.
- `\s` is yet again a set-matching operation.

Now compare this to @Stephen Rauch's suggested solution of splitting the input. (I'll only tackle the first solution

- First the input is `split` on `;`, which is a matter of advancing
  until a `;` is found, returning everything before the `;`, making a
  note of where the `;` is and continuing either to the next `;` or to
  the end. Importantly, this can be done lazily, with each split being
  generated only as required.
- Next `strip()` goes through the start of the string up until the
  first non-whitespace character and notes that as the start index,
  then it goes backwards from the end until it finds a non-whitespace
  character and marks that as the end index, then it's a simple matter
  of returning a substring.
- Finally the last operation is a matter of another `split` and an
  array index.

The split-based solution thus uses much simpler operations, which are both simpler and lazy, which leads to it being significantly faster. In this case the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) definately prevails.

Comment: Thanks @Pharap for your clarification. I agree with you about using builtin string methods over regex when possible but believe it or not that was not the most expensive part of my original code it was `set(sum(just_colors,[]))` - at least when it comes to these large dfs. For some reason using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is ~537x faster for specs noted in my comments for @Stephen Rauch's answer even though I'm still using the regex (b/c the data sets I'm working with are much more complicated than my simplified example).